# Project java with two packages, but a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException between the two

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javac

I have a intellij project, with two packages.
One of them call a list in the second.
The DB connection is ok (i put sysout everywhere to follow my request)
The problem happens when the class which is supposed to screen the List from the manager of the other package call it.

```
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("on est dans le servlet pour afficher les voitures");
        CarManager cm = new CarManager();
        List<Car> cars = cm.lister();
```

The problem happens at 'CarManager cm = new CarManager();'

it shows : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.example.CarManager
however, is it imported in my servlet : import org.example.CarManager; and i have no error in the IDE (red or something)
I tried to do a "javac" in the folder for carmanager and i had errors.

Problem is : i have no idea why or how to fix it.

Comment: It would appear that `CarManager` is not on your classpath at runtime, but it is on the classpath at compile time (that's why you don't get red squiggles in Intellij). It's hard to say why because we can't see your code, how you're running it etc. But that's the issue.

Comment: You need to specify how you build and launch the project

Comment: @DeeDee44 from the menu at top, try `Build -> Clean Project` & then `Build -> Rebuild Project` if doing this doesn't work then `File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart`

Comment: Hello ! thank you for answering ! 
Well, i run the project with tomcat 9
I tried the Build/clean, etc of Darshan answer but still doesn't work, i have the same error :(

Comment: OH WOW actually i found how to do (but totally by luck o_O) i changed my artifact in run configuration, just to try and it's ok ! i have no idea why but COOL i won't be killed by my school !

Answer (score 0):

If the Car Manager class in another package then you cannot include its functionality just by basic approach:

```
className objectName= new className();
```

for that to work you must first import it

```
import packagename.classname;
```

make sure that the class you want to import is public otherwise it will not work

Eg: Suppose I have 2 packages `a` and `b`. I want to import package `b`'s class `x`'s function `sayHello()` in `a`

I first make both the class and function to be imported as public and then in an I import it using:

```
import b.x;
```

then where I want to use the function I write:

```
x obj = new x();
obj.sayHello()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it, but totally by luck.

I changed my artifact in run configuration, just to try and it's ok!